# How to make a Histogram from a sqldf in python

Tags: python, plot, histogram, sqldf

I wrote the following SQL query in iPython notebook

```
q = """SELECT * 
FROM Northeast ORDER BY counted desc LIMIT 10"""
display(sqldf(q))

df = pysqldf(q)

plt.bar(df)
plt.show()
```

I was trying to make a histogram of it but I keep getting errors about it need a high etc. I try it in different ways getting different errors. Is it possible to make out of the result of a sgldf an bar histogram with the city as x axe and population as y axe?

Comment: just use `hist` rather than `bar`

Comment: also what's the difference between `pysqldf(q)` and `sqldf(q)`? Shouldn't it be `sqldf(q)` throughout?

Comment: By hist I get this eerror 
TypeError: len() of unsized object

Comment: It should be the same actually, I just triet it for case

Comment: I can't see the data, so I am not sure why your plot is not showing. Try using dataframe `dot` methods: `df.plot(kind='barh')`. Perhaps that'll give something.

Comment: The data has 10 cities and 10 numbers to each city

Comment: x should be the cityes and y the numbers

Comment: Since you still insist on not showing the data, I wrote a script that does something close to what you want. [Take a look](https://www.dropbox.com/s/okk31e0h6vmo5l1/northeast.py?dl=0). Let me know what you think.

Comment: It gives me this out <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x2c5f9fb9518> but dont show any histogram

Comment: You can just show that with `plt.show()`. I have edited it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/okk31e0h6vmo5l1/northeast.py?dl=0).

Comment: @Vedad, was that script helpful at all? If so, is it the answer to your question?

Comment: I just needet to define %matplotlib inline that was the problem. Now it works

Comment: @Vedad, just added the script as the answer. Please feel free to check it as the answer when you get a chance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script should help with what you are trying to do:

```
import pandas as pd
from pysqldf import SQLDF
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


##Set up the sqldf function to query from the globals() variables
sqldf = SQLDF(globals())
##Since you're using ipython notebooks, put plots in line with this: %matplotlib inline

##Get some data from Wikipedia: Gets all sorts of information on cities in the Northeast
cities = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northeastern_United_States',header = 0)
Northeast = cities[1] ##This where the top 10 cities are
Northeast.head(2) ## Take a look
Northeast.columns = ['Rank', 'MetropolitanArea', 'States', 'Population'] ##Change the columns to look better

##Run your query: This gets city name and Population
df = sqldf.execute('SELECT MetropolitanArea, Population FROM Northeast ORDER BY Population desc LIMIT 10;')

##This get the bar plot
df.plot(x='MetropolitanArea',y='Population',kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

Thanks!